# Ubuntu 17.10 change default user on login screen

Tags: login

I've got two users on my system 'A' and 'Z' and for some reason user 'Z' is always highlighted as the default user on the Ubuntu login screen.  User 'A' is the administrator, the most frequent user, and first in the alphabet, so I'm not sure why Ubuntu doesnt rank them as default.

Does anyone know how Ubuntu chooses which user to highlight and is there a way to select which user is the default highlighted user?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is not the *second* user that is highlighted but it is the one under the mouse pointer. And when you boot and don't move your mouse then the mouse pointer is in the center of the screen.

Hence, the user *in the center of the screen* is highlighted. On a two-user system this happens to be the second one.

Comment: ...and there was I being paranoid and thinking Ubuntu hated me and preferred the second user, obvious once you explain.  Thank you.

Comment: @Guy I wondered myself when I noticed this behaviour. It was different in Ubuntu 16 and before where the last logged-in user was highlighted. Still not sure which I like better. But I think there's some black/whitelist file as to control which users get displayed on the login screen. You could put `Z` on the blacklist.

Comment: It's a very minor inconvenience that the 17.10 setup uses the number of users to determine which to highlight rather than looking at machine usage.  IMO a more "intelligent" setup would be either to have the most frequent user highlighted, or as previous versions the last user logged-in.